# Laravel with slow subSelect query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery

When running query on website (ajax request, Laravel 5.7) it is performing in 99% fast (somewhere around 800ms) but in 1% the total execution of query could be up to 50 seconds.

What is the problem of this behaviour, is there any kind of caching? Also, should anything be optimized?

Here is query (@numbers -> here comes array with up to 250 numbers):

```
SELECT
var.g_id,
var.title,
lm_object.title AS ht_title,
lm_object.image_checked_at,
var.cot,
var.cca,
var.cot_cca,
var.rating,
var.lm_object_id AS var_id,
lm_object.id AS hot_id,
(SELECT link FROM lm_images WHERE typ = 1 AND thumb = 1 AND 
( id = var.id OR cot _cca = var.cot _cca ) LIMIT 1 ) AS th,
(SELECT link FROM lm_images WHERE typ = 2 AND thumb = 1 AND 
( id = var.id OR cot_cca = var.cot _cca ) LIMIT 1 ) AS th_1 
FROM lm_object
INNER JOIN lm_object_sar AS var ON lm_ object.id = var.lm_object_id 
WHERE
var.id IN ( @numbers...) 
AND lm_object.deleted_at IS NULL
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:

```html
<table width="973" border="1"><thead><tr><td width="88"><p><strong>id</strong></p></td><td width="88"><p><strong>select_type</strong></p></td><td width="89"><p><strong>table</strong></p></td><td width="88"><p><strong>type</strong></p></td><td width="109"><p><strong>possible_keys</strong></p></td><td width="68"><p><strong>key</strong></p></td><td width="88"><p><strong>key_len</strong></p></td><td width="88"><p><strong>ref</strong></p></td><td width="89"><p><strong>rows</strong></p></td><td width="88"><p><strong>Extra</strong></p></td><td width="89">&nbsp;</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td width="88"><p>1</p></td><td width="88"><p>PRIMARY</p></td><td width="89"><p>var</p></td><td width="88"><p>range</p></td><td width="109"><p>g_id_cot_cca,g_id,lm_objects_id</p></td><td width="68"><p>g_id_cot_cca</p></td><td width="88"><p>5</p></td><td width="88"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="89"><p>246</p></td><td width="88"><p>Using index condition; Using where</p></td><td width="89">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="88"><p>1</p></td><td width="88"><p>PRIMARY</p></td><td width="89"><p>lm_objects</p></td><td width="88"><p>eq_ref</p></td><td width="109"><p>PRIMARY</p></td><td width="68"><p>PRIMARY</p></td><td width="88"><p>4</p></td><td width="88"><p>mydb.var.lm_objects_id</p></td><td width="89"><p>1</p></td><td width="88"><p>Using where</p></td><td width="89">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="88"><p>3</p></td><td width="88"><p>DEPENDENT SUBQUERY</p></td><td width="89"><p>lm_images</p></td><td width="88"><p>ALL</p></td><td width="109"><p>g_id,cot</p></td><td width="68"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="88"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="88"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="89"><p>119603</p></td><td width="88"><p>Using where</p></td><td width="89">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="88"><p>2</p></td><td width="88"><p>DEPENDENT SUBQUERY</p></td><td width="89"><p>lm_images</p></td><td width="88"><p>ALL</p></td><td width="109"><p>g_id,cot</p></td><td width="68"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="88"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="88"><p><em>NULL</em></p></td><td width="89"><p>119603</p></td><td width="88"><p>Using where</p></td><td width="89">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these queries as part of this big query

```
(SELECT link FROM lm_images WHERE typ = 1 AND thumb = 1 AND 
( id = var.id OR cot _cca = var.cot _cca ) LIMIT 1 ) AS th,
(SELECT link FROM lm_images WHERE typ = 2 AND thumb = 1 AND 
( id = var.id OR cot_cca = var.cot _cca ) LIMIT 1 ) AS th_1
```

as they don't contribute too much towards the result. Add these two column seperately.

Comment: Inside whereIn method there is like 250 numbers, sometimes more. This way I have to manually match all. Not sure if this will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try and see what your query plan looks like.  You can check that using the `EXPLAIN` command.  It'll show you where you might increase performance by adding indices where needed.

Secondly, I always prefer avoiding subselects.  You can rewrite the above query using additional joins on the outer select, and filter them out as soon as you can.  You might try the following and see how it compares:

```
SELECT *
FROM lm_object
INNER JOIN lm_object_sar var
  ON lm_object.id = var.lm_object_id
LEFT JOIN lm_images img1
  ON img1.typ = 1
  AND img1.thumb = 1
  AND (
    img1.id = var.id
    OR img1.cot_cca = var.cot_cca
  )
LEFT JOIN lm_images img2
  ON img2.typ = 2
  AND img2.thumb = 1
  AND (
    img2.id = var.id
    OR img2.cot_cca = var.cot_cca
  )
WHERE var.id IN (@numbers...)
AND lm_object.deleted_at IS NULL
```

Please note that the above will return multiple rows if you can have more img1 and img2 records; I see you applied a `LIMIT 1` which makes me think you can have more rows there as a result of these filters.

If this is the case, it's probably better to just separately query them in your code than trying to squeeze it into one "large" query.

Also, consider monitoring your application using a service such as newRelic; it can give you insights into what exactly caused that 50 second delay there.  Are you sure it's your database query?

Comment: There should be only one image of each type, limit was just for nothing there. About query, I logged times before laravel query and after, so there is also a possibility that laravel does not build query fast. Will check that too. I updated question.

Comment: You might want to try and add indices to g_id,cot for lm_images table...